# How to click on the heatmap series data on echarts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, echarts

I have created a heatmap using the apache e-charts library. How can I click the particular data on heatmap  render the another chat on that data?

Is there a way to  heatmap series data when the click event is triggered for the another heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Your chart>.on('click', function (params) {
    window.open('Your Link');
});
```

Refer to: https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20Actions%20in%20ECharts